# Run post processing commands on remote server from informatica cloud

Tags: etl, informatica, post-processing, informatica-cloud

I am running a job on informatica cloud. It picks up a file from a server (remote) and dumps the data into salesforce. I want to run post processing commands from informatica cloud on the source file which is present in the remote server after the informatica job finishes. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Files need to present in the Agent installed machine.
Post processing command file cannot be present in remote location.